# Set values inside an already populated Integer ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays

As the question states I want to `add` (perform an arithmetic operation of addition) values to an integer ArrayList that has already been populated with some values. I Know how to sum an entire array list and output a single `int` value but I don't want that. Say that I have an `int` arraylist as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

`a` contains the following entries:

```
{5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

and an `int` variable:

```
int b = 25;
```

now I want to add `b` into every single entry inside the array list `a` so that the array list becomes:

```
 a = {30,31,32,33,34,35};
```

I've tried just simply using `a.add(b)` but that just replaces every single entry inside `a` with 25.

Comment: `int []` is an array of ints, not an `ArrayList` which is a different Class and Object type altogether. I'm surprised you say `a.add(b)` compiled and had any effect at all, because I'm not aware that arrays have a method called `add` at all

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Sorry I was being lazy and couldn't figure how how to write what I wanted to convey so I just copied and pasted whatever came first on a google search...I've change the post with the proper code now.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I realize that and I'm sorry..

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
  array.set(i, array.get(i) + addValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following block of code

```
 int []a = {5,6,7,8,9,10};
    
 for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = a[i] + 25;
 }
```